# Programatically set values of html form loaded by button click in iframe content (Javascript or C# code behind)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have an ASP.NET web application with different tab controls.

In tab control A I have a user control embeded that allows queries and filling form.

In tab control B I have an iframe referencing an external source / page from different domain.
When iframe content in Tab control B is loaded a button is clicked to load an HTML from the same domain.This form has a drop down with 3 options lets name it 'options',when clicked it loads a textbox named "textbox" and has a button named 'submit'.

All these work when user clicks them but I have a requirement to fill them programatically and submit the form from tab control A.I want to change dropdown,set text of textbox and fire onclick on 'submit' button.

Please help with Javascript,jQuery or C# code.
Thank you.

Comment: first try your self, and come here and ask question if you have trouble

Comment: I have tried to get iframe embedding external page by id and attempted to find the elements but failed misrably.`var x = document.getElementById('myframe');
                        
                        alert("iframe using frames=" + window.frames['myframe']);

                        var e = window.frames['myframe'].document.getElementById('options');
                        alert("Got element by id from iframe" + e);`